# How to get users to honestly describe work priority

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, prioritization

I am designing a tool who's GUI allows scientific users within my company to submit requests for long simulations to be run on a shared, limited compute resource.

When the users submit they're request, I want to present them with an option for how urgent their simulations are (which would then inform how much processing power they are allocated). My concern is that when presented with options such as "Low, Medium, High" or "Not urgent, urgent, critical" users will by default select the "High" or "critical" in attempt to get their simulations completed faster.

Are there ways of presenting a priority input that would encourage users to give an honest assessment of how urgent their request is? I initially thought about attempting to provide a time estimate for each priority class however that has proven difficult to predict. My only other alternative (that I can see) is treat all user requests as equal and not allow for priority submissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prioritization of work should be based on the impact of the work to the business.** Instead of asking users to assess the urgency of their needs (which can result in the “everything is always on fire” people always gaining priority), ask for the impact of the requested simulation on the business - Low, medium, high, extreme. Combine this with a requested due date.

If the impact is Extreme, ask for an explanation. If their simulation is truly important to the business, your user will have a solid answer. If they just want it ASAP for no good reason, their answer will be more vague. You can use this feedback to make value judgements on prioritizing the work.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I like this option best for forcing the user to put in words the reason for their decision without penalising truly urgent cases. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simple way to predict this, but you can get ideas from how SE works to make a user prioritize their question: [*What is a bounty?*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

> - All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any
>   circumstances.
> - Users may only have three active bounties at any given time.
> - Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time.
> - You may not cancel a bounty once it has been started.

If you read how a bounty question works, you will see that it's not "free", but you must remove part of your earned reputation. From here you can get many ideas, personally I would try two options:

1 - Put a system of weekly tokens in the workers and assign an amount to
each of the three options so there's not only the option of
choosing the level of urgency but also trying to manage it. For
example:

- Not urgent = 2 tokens
- Urgent = 3 tokens
- Critical = 5 tokens

2 - Establish a period of time with a certain number of request
priorities, for example, in a week 2 critical, 3 urgent and 4 not
urgent.

In short, force the user to manage their request assignments.